# WindowsFormsHost in WPF MDI on Aero main form (C#)

Tags: wpf, mdi, aero, avalondock, windowsformshost

My crazy problem: I'm using a docking system (AvalonDock) on a WPF form with aero glass style background (what looks really nice). In one dockable MDI I need a WinForms custom control, so I just used the `WindowsFormsHost` that loads my control successfully. But there is one problem:

The `WindowsFormsHost` shows the glass background of the main form for the amount of black for all colors used in the custom control.

Changing the MDI background doesn't help because the `WindowsFormsHost` cuts a hole through everything in the WPF MDI.

Concluding neither trying to have white text on a black background nor the other way round makes the textbox in my custom control clearly readable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What control are you using that needs WindowsFormsHost?

Comment: A custom control (something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9621/ShellControl-A-console-emulation-control)